# Need to compare objects from an ArrayList to return the highest value

Tags: java, object, arraylist, compare

In this project (using BlueJ as I am a beginner) I am looking to add Climbers to an ArrayList with their name, gender and age. The Climbers can add what mountain they have climbed. With the mountain name and height.

I need to add a method into the Climber class to return which is the highest mountain a certain Climber has climbed.

To define the method do I define it using

```
public ArrayList<Mountain> getHighestMountain(Mountain mountainHeight)
```

I am unsure as how to check the objects in the mountain class to compare. FYI I haven't been learned the comparative keyword yet so would like to refrain from using this.

Club class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Write a description of class Club here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Club
{
    // An ArrayList for storing climber details.
    private ArrayList<Climber> climbers;

    /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Club
    */
    public Club()
   {
       // Initialise instance variables.
       climbers = new ArrayList<Climber>();
    }

    public void addClimber(Climber newName)
    {
        climbers.add(newName);
    }


   public Climber getClimber(String name)
   {
       Climber foundClimber = null;
       int index = 0;
       boolean searching = true;

       while(searching && index < climbers.size()) {
           Climber climber = climbers.get(index);
           if(climber.getName().equals(name)) {
                   searching = false;
                   foundClimber = climber;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(name + " not found");
                    index++;
                }
            }
            return foundClimber;
        }

    public void displayClimberList()
    {
        for (int item = 0; item<climbers.size();
        item++) {
            Climber climber = climbers.get(item);
            System.out.println(climber.getName() + (" ") + climber.getAge() + (" ") 
            + climber.getGender());
        }
    }

}
```

Climber class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Write a description of class Climber here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Climber
{
    // Instance variables.
    // The climber name.
    private String name;
    // The climber age
    private int age;
    // The climber gender.
    private String gender;
    private ArrayList<Mountain> mountains;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Climber
     */
    public Climber (String newName, int newAge, String newGender)
    {
        // Initialise instance variables.
        name = newName;
        age = newAge;
        gender = newGender;
        mountains = new ArrayList<Mountain>();

    }

    /**
     * Accessor method for climber's name.
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Set the climber's name.
     */
    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor method for climber's age.
     */
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;

    }

    /**
     * Set the climber's age.
     */
    public void setAge(int newAge)
    {
        age = newAge;

    }

     /**
     * Set the climer's gender.
     */
   public String getGender()
   {
       return gender;
   } 

   /**
     * Accessor method for climber's gender.
     */
    public void getGender(String newGender)
    {
        gender = newGender;

    }

   public Mountain addMountain(Mountain mountain)
   {
       return mountain;
    } 

   public ArrayList<Mountain> getHighestMountain(Mountain mountainHeight)
   {
       double maxHeight = 1;
       int index = 1;
       for(int i = 0; i < mountainHeight.length; i++) {
           if(mountainHeight[i].getHeight()>maxHeight) {
               index = i;
            }
        }




    }
}
```

Mountain class:

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Mountain here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Mountain
{
    // Instance variables.
    private double height;
    private String name;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Mountain
     */
    public Mountain(String mountainName, double mountainHeight)
    {
        // Initialise instance variables
        name = mountainName;
        height = mountainHeight;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor method for mountain name.
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Set the mountain name.
     */
    public void setName(String mountainName)
    {
        name = mountainName;
    }

    /**
     * Accessor method for mountain height.
     */
    public double getHeight()
    {
        // put your code here
        return height;
    }

    /**
     * Set the mountain height.
     */
    public void setHeight(double newHeight)
    {
        height = mountainHeight;
    }
}
```

I've attempted to return this value but as you can see it is incomplete.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to update your maxHeight variable to the actual max height you found. Currently you are allway comparing if the mountain is higher than 1. Also: Why would this method return an ArrayList of Mountains? You are looking for a single Mountain. And why pass an existing Mountain into it? The Climber already has a list of Mountains as a field. I don't see why you need to pass anything into that function as a parameter.

Comment: Also `getHighestMountain` should probably return only one `Mountain`, not a whole list .

Comment: There are many things wrong here. Your addMountain method adds nothing, it just returns the parameter. Your getHighestMountain does not return a Mountain, but an ArrayList of Mountains. You're looping over a parameter that is a Mountain, instead of a List and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Comments**

Get rid of your comments, they are not adding any value. Don't put or leave default comments in your code, they reduce readability. Clarifications should also be avoided, try to create a separate variable or method with a meaningful name instead. For example:

```
// check if the user is on the last page
if (!((count - i) < pageSize)) {
    addNextButton();
}
```

Could become:

```
boolean userIsOnTheLastPage = (count - i) < pageSize;
if (!userIsOnTheLastPage) {
    addNextButton();
}
```

**Interfaces**

Java collections (like ArrayList) implement interfaces (e.g. List). Usually you will want to declare and pass around the interface, not the implementation you used. Other parts of your code should only care about using the List capabilities, not how they are implemented.

So replace;

```
private ArrayList<Climber> climbers;
```

with

```
private List<Climber> climbers;
```

Also use the interface as parameter or return type in methods. A result of this approach is that if you want to use a different List implementation later on, you only have to change it in one place in your code. This is a form of decoupling in your code, which is a good thing to have. ('low coupling, high cohesion')

**getClimber**

Your search implementation in getClimber is a bit convoluted. I'd do it like this:

```
for (Climber climber : climbers) {
    if(climber.getName().equals(name)) {
        return climber;
    }   
}       
System.out.println(name + " not found");
```

I understand you might be trying to avoid returning from an iteration but in my opinion the code gets much less readable as a result.
BTW your code would print 'not found' for every non-matching climber. I assumed that's not what you want so my code only prints it once if no matching climber is found.

**displayClimberList**

```
public void displayClimbers() {
    for (Climber climber : climbers) {
        System.out.println(climber);
    }
}
```

System.out.println calls `toString()` on its argument, so we can leave the formating of the display String to the Climber class:

```
public class Climber {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;

    // ...

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s %s", name, age, gender);
    }
```

- Don't mention types in your variable/method names if not needed. The fact that a List is returned is already apparent from the method signature.
- foreach is more readable an iteration with an index so use it when you can. Sometimes you cannot avoid using an index, for example when iterating through two lists simultaneously but that's not the case here.
- printf (or String.format) makes formatting an output string much easier than String concatenation. See the [documentation of java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

**Gender**

I would change the gender field from String to enum:

```
public class Climber {

    private Gender gender;
```

The enum could look like this:

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE;
}
```

(that's a separate top-level class, so in a file called Gender.java). See also [the Oracle tutorial about enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

**addMountain**

Fix the addMountain method so it actually adds a mountain:

```
public void addMountain(Mountain mountain) {
    mountains.add(mountain);
}
```

**getHighestMountain**

The logic of getHighestMountain is flawed (this was your question), try this:

```
public List<Mountain> getHighestMountain() {
    Mountain highest = null;
    for(Mountain mountain : mountains) {
        if(highest == null || mountain.getHeight() > highest.getHeight()) {
            highest = mountain;
        }
     }
     return highest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
//This does absolutely nothing. It takes a parameter and returns it.
public Mountain addMountain(Mountain mountain) {
    return mountain;
} 

public ArrayList<Mountain> getHighestMountain(Mountain mountainHeight) {
    double maxHeight = 1;
    int index = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < mountainHeight.length; i++) {
        if(mountainHeight[i].getHeight()>maxHeight) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
}
```

To:

```
//This adds the parameter mountain to the list of mountains for this climber
public void addMountain(Mountain mountain) {
    mountains.add(mountain);
} 

//This loops over the mountains for this climber and returns the highest one. 
public Mountain getHighestMountain() {
    Mountain highestMountain = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < mountains.size(); i++) {
        if (highestMountain == null) {
            highestMountain = mountains.get(i);
        }
        else if(mountains.get(i).getHeight() > highestMountain.getHeight()) {
            highestMountain = mounts.get(i);
        }
    }
    return highestMountain;
}
```

Your code example shows a lack of understanding of basic concepts such as fields and variables, parameters and return types and so on. I would suggest reading up on the language basics [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html).